# RStudio, issue with pdflatex converting .tex to pdf file

Tags: r, pdflatex, miktex

I am trying to run a conversion using pdflatex of output.tex to a pdf and it gives me this error message:
The output.tex was created using knitr using data_exploration_report.Rnw file

```
knit(report_file, output = file_name)

"Sorry, but C:\\Users\\app1ebb\\DOCUME~1\\R\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\pdflatex.exe did not succeed."
```

And then the warnings:

```
Warning message:
running command 'C:/Users/app1ebb/Documents/R/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe C:/Users/app1ebb/Documents/AA/RToolkit/exploration-kit/temp/output.tex' had status 1
```

I looked at the log and I can not make sense out of it:

```
2017-12-18 16:31:12,565-0500 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: C:\Users\app1ebb\DOCUME~1\R\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe C:/Users/app1ebb/Documents/AA/RToolkit/exploration-kit/temp/output.tex
2017-12-18 16:31:12,572-0500 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2017-12-18 16:31:12,573-0500 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2017-12-18 16:31:12,928-0500 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-12-18 16:31:12,928-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2017-12-18 16:31:12,928-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-12-18 16:31:12,928-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 45
2017-12-18 16:31:12,928-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

Im running Windows 10  and I can see that my MikTeX is on my path already
. I am running R version 3.4.2 and RStudio 1.1.383

And here is my path:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
    [1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.2\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Program Files\\VanDyke Software\\Clients\\;c:\\OracleClient32\\oracle\\product\\client\\11.2.0\\32Bit\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\avs\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\avs\\bin32;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Users\\WindowsHelp\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\WinZip;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CheckPoint\\Endpoint Security\\Endpoint Common\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\IDM Computer Solutions\\UltraEdit;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\app1ebb\\Documents\\R\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Users\\app1ebb\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

Comment: Did it save a file named `output.log` in the same directory as `output.tex`?  That will contain the log from MikTeX.  It's often very long; look near the bottom for error messages.